# ggplot2 different label for the first break

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am plotting events in `ggplot2` and want to be able to tell the entire date time of the event, but not have cumbersome axis labels.

The events are normally a few hours up to a few days, possibly up to a couple of weeks, and are all in one data set. Sometimes I'm plotting them separately or faceting the plot, so hopefully any solution would work with either method. As many of the events only go for a few hours overall the default breaks are good (i.e. in my example below for an event 'a' break every 3 hours makes sense) but you cannot tell when they are, in this example these 9 hours could be on any day of any month of any year. I'm looking for a smart way to show that this is January the 1st 2001 without that having to be repeated for each break point. My idea was that the first break could have all the info but the ones after remain the same, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach or how to do it if so.

**Example data and plot:** (obviously not real data. In real life the events are calculated through an automatic process so I won't know the start or end dates or how long they go for, so can't have any hard coded breaks etc)

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

testdata <- data.frame(
  DateTime = ymd_h("20010101 15", "20010102 00", "20030303 03",
                    "20030305 00","20070205 00","20070205 10"),
  Value = runif(6),
  Event = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2)
)

ggplot(testdata, aes(x = DateTime, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Event, scale = "free")
```

[image]
I wondered about setting date_breaks and date_minor_breaks but it looks pretty bad even with only a few events of not that different lengths. If I added a long (say 10 day) event it would look really bad.

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(x = DateTime, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Event, scale = "free")+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "day", date_minor_breaks = "3 hours"
                    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to write a function for `date_labels`

This function gives the full date/time for the first label and then just the hours/minutes for the other labels. You could make the format an argument, or add some simple heuristics to change the format according to the duration.

```
first_date <- function(x){
  lab <- as.vector(x)
  lab[!is.na(x)] <- c(
    format(x = x[!is.na(x)][1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
    format(x = x[!is.na(x)][-1], format = "%H:%M")
  )
  lab
}

ggplot(testdata, aes(x = DateTime, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Event, scale = "free") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = first_date) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Sweet thank you. I knew in theory that you could write your own functions for `date_labels` but never realised is was this simple/how you would make the first one different. Thanks!